# getApplicationIcon() from packageManager not returning Gallery app icon

Tags: android, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose, android-gallery, android-package-managers

Attempting to get the default Gallery app icon on my Samsung phone with `packageManager` returns the Files app icon instead. How can I get the Gallery app's icon?

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null)
intent.setType("image/*")
val appInfo = LocalContext.current.packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) // Also tried MATCH_ALL
val icon = appInfo?.loadIcon(LocalContext.current.packageManager)
```

It returns this icon [image] with the package name `com.google.android.documentsui`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the `ACTION_PICK` Intent instead. It works now.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    
// Returns the com.sec.android.gallery3d package name
```